# Look up status of Facebook and Twitter liking/following by a user

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

For a contest on our website, I would like people to like our page on Facebook or follow us on Twitter. Is there a way for me to check the status of said interactions from my website?

Comment: Lots of sites allow you to see all the data in one place, I use: http://home.sproutsocial.com/social-marketing/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=UK+Social+Media&utm_content=Social+Media+Stats+Exact&utm_term=social%20media%20stats